# Nvidia DIGITS - Learning Rate Ambiguity

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

What is the difference between Base Learning rate in Nvidia Digits UI during training and Learning rate param(lr_pm) for each layer defined in the caffe .prototxt file. Finally which learning rate is used?

Comment: it's the product of the two

Comment: you mean `lr_multi` or `lrn_param` or both ?

Comment: [`lrn_param`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L401) has nothing to do with learning rate: it stores paramters for [`"LRN"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/lrn.html) layer.

Answer (score 0):

The learning rate for a particular layer is the **global learning rate** multiplied with the **lr_mult** of that specific layer.